# Combination of functools.partialmethod and classmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, class-method, functools

I would like to use `functools.partialmethod` on a classmethod. However the behavior I find is not what I would expect (and like to have).
Here is an example:

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def h(cls, x, y):
        print(cls, x, y)

class B(A):
    h = functools.partialmethod(A.h, "fixed")
```

When I do

```
>>> b = B()
>>> b.h(3)
```

I get an error:

```
...
TypeError: h() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

This is consistent with

```
>>> b.h()
<class '__main__.A'> <__main__.B object at 0x1034739e8> fixed
```

However, I would expect (and like to have) the following behavior:

```
>>> b.h(4)
<class '__main__.B'> fixed 4
```

I think that `functools.partialmethod` treats `B.h` as a normal instance method and passes the actual instance as first argument automatically.
But this behavior renders `functools.partialmethod` useless for freezing arguments in classmethods of inheriting classes.

Comment: ```b.h()``` or ```b.c()```?

Comment: You want to override a class method in a parent class by *fixing* one of its arguments?

Comment: Will all of the parameters be positional or keyword or a mix?

Comment: They'll be a mix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going into too much detail, the `partial` object doesn't mix well with the descriptor protocol that `@classmethod` utilizes to create a class instance. The simple fix is to just define your overridden method in the usual fashion:

```
class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def h(cls, y):
        return A.h("fixed", y)
```

---

It *might* be possible to do what you want with some invocation of `partial`, but I was unable to find it. Here are some of my attempts, and why they failed.

`A.h` invokes the `__get__` method of the function object, returning a function where the first argument is already bound to the calling class. `partial` then applies that function to `"fixed"`, but then the resulting callable *still* has a `__get__` method that tries to insert the calling class into the resulting call. You might try to work around that by defining `h` to actually be a *static* method:

```
class B(A):
    h = staticmethod(partial(A.h, "fixed"))

>>> B.h(4)
<class '__main__.A'> fixed 4
```

But as you can see, you already froze the class argument when you call `partial`. Another attempt is to avoid the descriptor protocol by accessing the argument directly:

```
class B(A):
    h = staticmethod(partial(A.__dict__["h"], "fixed"))
```

but `classmethod` objects aren't actually callable; only the return value of their `__get__` methods is, so the call to `partial` fails.

Comment: Explicitly calling `A.c` in the `B` overload is bad form, since you'll lose information about the "true" class (and classmethods are typically alternate constructors, so losing that information is a problem). Change it to `return super().c("fixed", y)` so it passes up the correct class (and handles multiple inheritance properly too).

Comment: `super` implies that you are *always* going to use `super` in a parent class and you will always use `super` in any child classes. It's not just as simple as "hey, I don't have to hard-code my parent class's name". You can't just say one is right, the other is wrong; both have their uses, benefits, and drawbacks.

Comment: It really is that simple in 99% of cases (the other 1% are typically misuses of `classmethod`). `A.c` passes `A` as the `cls`, `super().c` passes `B` as the `cls`. If you use the former, then the `@classmethod` decoration serves no purpose beyond allowing you to say `cls` instead of `A` in the method; otherwise, it's just `@staticmethod`, because you've thrown away the one piece of unique information that `@classmethod` provides. You're no longer using any useful feature of `B` that a plain function calling `A` wouldn't provide equally well.

Comment: None of which is really relevant to the question at hand, which is about combining `partial` and `classmethod`.

Comment: Then why illustrate incorrect usage? I'm just saying you shouldn't simplify answers so much that they introduce new mistakes, when doing it correctly costs nothing.

Comment: `A.h` was used in the question; I'm preserving that in the answer. I'm not getting to a debate about whether or not `super` should be used here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) (v2.7)

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def c(cls, x, y):
        print('cls:{}, x:{}, y:{}'.format(cls, x, y))

class B(A):
    def c(self, y):
        super(B, self).c(x = 'fixed', y = y) 

class C(A):
    def c(self, x):
        super(C, self).c(x = x, y = 'fixed') 

b = B()
c = C()

>>> 
>>> b.c(4)
cls:<class '__main__.B'>, x:fixed, y:4
>>> c.c(4)
cls:<class '__main__.C'>, x:4, y:fixed
>>>
```

---

[super is super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: FYI, Python 3 (which this question is tagged) doesn't require explicit arguments for `super` in most cases. It's a lot easier (and [non-DRY violating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) to just call `super().c`.

Comment: I really want to avoid explicitly overriding. In my case there are much more arguments in the place of y and typing them all is very error prone and too much work. I could use `h(x,*args)` syntax, but then this info is missing in the docs.

Comment: @ShadowRanger ... I only have 2.7 here at work so I couldn't test/play in 3.x, thats why I spec'd the version.